# Identify records with multiple distinct values in one-to-may relationship

Tags: sql-server

In this example, I'm trying to have a query that will tell me who has more than one distinct address in the address table.  Using SQL Server 2017.

```
CREATE TABLE Person (PersonId int, FirstName varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE [Address] (PersonId int, [Address] varchar(50))

INSERT INTO Person VALUES (1, 'Person has multiple addresses')
INSERT INTO Person VALUES (2, 'Person has only one address')

INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (1, 'Address 1')
INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (1, 'Address 2')
INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (1, 'Address 2')

INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (2, 'Address 3')
INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (2, 'Address 3')
```

In this simple example, the person that I conveniently named "Person has multiple addresses" has a total of two distinct addresses, "Address 1" and "Address 2."  The person named "Person has only one address" has just one, "Address 3."

The pseudo query I have is like this, but this is clearly not right.  I'm trying to distill down all unique values from the "[Address]" column for each person, and return only those with more than one.

```
SELECT
    p.FirstName
FROM
    Person p
    INNER JOIN [Address] a ON p.PersonId = a.PersonId
HAVING
    COUNT(a.*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Count(a.*)` counts the number of rows (in this case 2). You want to use a `distinct` to only count distinct values in those rows instead.

```
SELECT
    p.FirstName
FROM
    Person p
    INNER JOIN [Address] a ON p.PersonId = a.PersonId
group by p.firstname
HAVING COUNT(distinct a.Address) > 1
```